# How to allocate?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$capture_field_vals ="";
foreach($_POST["mytext"] as $key => $text_field)
{
   $capture_field_vals .= $text_field .", ";
}   
$insert = "INSERT INTO tabel1(numbers) VALUES('$capture_field_vals')";
```

in database it is (5342324, 23432423, 24234242, 234234234)

and what i  want to do..

```
$insert2 = "INSERT INTO tabel2(number1, number2, number3, number4) VALUES('$capture_field_vals[0]','$capture_field_vals[1]','$capture_field_vals[2]','$capture_field_vals[3]')";
```

Comment: Describe more.. What problems you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$capture_field_vals=Array();    
     foreach($_POST["mytext"] as $key => $text_field){
          array_push($capture_field_vals,$text_field);
     }
```

Then

```
$insert2 = "INSERT INTO tabel2(number1, number2, number3, number4)  VALUES('$capture_field_vals[0]','$capture_field_vals[1]','$capture_field_vals[2]','$capture_field_vals[3]')";
```

Comment: Array declaration...
A capital...
And i used second part same as question so that he can implement it quickly

Comment: Im first time in stackoverflow, how i can accept answer and why i cant vote up this answer ? :(

Comment: No problem @Erki.. Have fun and great coding ahead.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If there is dynamic fields in DB means number of fields is equal to size of array in POST variable then this code will work for you.

```
$capture_field_vals = $capture_fields = "";
$count = 1;
foreach($_POST["mytext"] as $key => $text_field) {
if ($capture_field_vals != "") {
    $capture_field_vals .= ", ";
}
if ($capture_fields != "") {
    $capture_fields .= ", ";
}
$capture_fields .= "number".$count;
$capture_field_vals .= $text_field;
$count++;
}
```

Then the insert query will be

```
$insert2 = "INSERT INTO tabel2(".$capture_fields.") VALUES (".$capture_field_vals.")";
```